Can we say that it is inability of LLMs to generate only single token in single pass during inference?
Suppose I prompt an LLM(e.g. ChatGPT) a below question.
When did Hitler die?

To which it replied as
Adolf Hitler died on April 30, 1945. He committed suicide in his bunker in Berlin as World War II was coming to an end in Europe.

Suppose now I ask
When did Donald Trump die?

and it replies as
As of today, Donald Trump is still alive. He was born on June 14, 1946, and remains an active political figure in the United States.

LLMs produce answers in a sequential manner word-by-word or in general token-by-token. So when I asked about Hitler's death the first few words generated were Adolf Hilter died on and when I asked about Donald Trump's death it started generating from the word As.
As per the architecture of LLM, its whole job is only to predict the next word using billions of parameters.
For the first answer when LLM was generating Adolf as the first word, the model must have incorporated the whole answer somewhere in Transformer that Adolf is actually dead so the first word should be Adolf and the same for Donald Trump, before generating the first word As the knowledge must have flown somehow in Transformer that Donald Trump is not dead yet and first word should be As.

So from the above conclusion, can we say that for any prompt the model actually knows the whole answer in hand but it is architecture's inability to give it in a single chunk? (And if it is a case then it should be a research topic to develop an architecture which generates answers in single pass)
What if we prompt the model with the given input When did Donald Trump die? <EOS> <SOS> Donald Trump died on. Yes, it is not possible through online interface like Chatgpt.com but from python surely we can do this.
If the conclusion that, model knows the whole answer in hand when prompted is true then I think we can also train a model with the below format and it still able to answer things in same way.

WordN WordN-1 WordN-2 ... Word3 Word2 Word1 <EOS> <SOS> AnswerWordN AnswerWordN-1 AnswerWordN-2 ... AnswerWord3 AnswerWord2 AnswerWord1
Yes during inference we have to give question in reverse and will get answer in reverse but it would still work, right?


Can we say that it is inability of LLMs to generate only single token in single pass during inference?

No, some LLM can generate multiple tokens in single pass during inference, e.g. see Better & Faster Large Language Models via Multi-token Prediction.
